# How to get only the 10 first entry tags using XSLT?

Tags: xslt, stylesheet

In a feedburner RSS I use

```
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

to get all the content of a feed with structure like below :

```
<feed>
<entry><published></published><title></title><content></content>....</entry>
</feed>
```

My question is, if it is possible to get only the 10 first `<entry></entry>` instead of all the 25 ? How to do it ?

Note : The entry tag has this form `<entry gd:etag="W/&quot;AkcHRH8yfSp7ImA9WhdUFkg.&quot;">` I do not know if this matters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

smth like

```
/feed/entry[position()<10]
```

I mean, you need add this template:

```
<xsl:template match="entry[position() &gt; 10]"/>
```

That drop all the entries after 10's, or something equal. The main suggestion is to take a look at `position()` function.

Comment: **+1**. Note that this is an XPath selector, and not XSLT per se.

Comment: The entry tag has this form `<entry gd:etag="W/&quot;AkcHRH8yfSp7ImA9WhdUFkg.&quot;">` I do not know if this matters

Comment: Don'y you mean `&lt;`? That selects everything **but** the first 10 entries.

Comment: @Eric: no, I mean `&gt;` (`>`), so my template DROP(!!!) all entries with `position() > 10`. All entries with `position() < 10` (which author needs to be showed) will be handled and displayed by default `<xsl:template match="node() | @*">` template.

Comment: @seriyPS: Ah, I see. That's a very strange way to write it.

Answer (score 0):

Your template was recursive. You then changed the behaviour of the outer template, breaking the recursion.

The simplest way to do what you want would be:

```
<xsl:template match="/feed/entry[position() &lt; 10]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: this doesn't works correctly, because `/feed/entry[position() &lt; 3]` match first 3 posts, but `node() | @*` matchs rest after 3'd

Comment: @seriyPS: Not sure what you mean. My code doesn't contain `node() | @*`

Comment: Yes, your code don't, but resulting code will contain at least 2 templates, one your and one `<xsl:template match="node() | @*">` from question I think. So, your template match first 10 entries, but all other entries will be successfully handled by 2-nd template.

Comment: @reiyPS: No it won't. Because I'm using `copy-of`, I don't need a `<xsl:template match="node() | @*">`.